# Getting an "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" on this String.Chars() array that shouldnt happen

Tags: vb.net, string, html-agility-pack

Anyone able to decipher how its possible I am getting this "System.IndexOutOfRangeException"? I have looked over the code, and its impossible for the String to even be empty, as the method I have created will, if it catches an exception, return a String with the word "Nothing" in it.

Here is where I am getting the exception:

```
Do While (Not (nodeStep Is Nothing))
    stepCmd = cmd + (XPathCommand.STEPCMD + ("/tr[" + stepCount.ToString + "]"))
    stepString = htmlManager.GetTextbyNode(htmlManager.GetNodebyXPath(stepCmd))
    stepChar = stepString.Chars(0) '<--- Exception thrown here!
    Select Case stepChar
        Case "D"
            testScript.StepDesc.Add(stepString.Replace("Description: ", ""))
        Case "E"
            testScript.StepExpect.Add(stepString.Replace("Expected: ", ""))
        Case "S"
            If Not (testScript.StepDesc.Count = testScript.StepExpect.Count) Then
                testScript.StepExpect.Add("< No expected step here >")
            End If
    End Select
    stepCount += 1
    nodeStep = htmlManager.GetNodebyXPath(cmd + (XPathCommand.STEPCMD + ("/tr[" + stepCount.ToString + "]")))
Loop
```

Now the htmlManager.GetTextbyNode method itself is where it takes an HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode and returns all the text in a node, after cleaning up the Text String first. The thing is, is that the method has a catch all (for nodes that don't have any text in them) to return the String "Nothing" back, as so:

```
Function GetTextbyNode(ByVal node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode) As String
    Try
        Return StringCleaner.Clean(node.InnerText)
    Catch
        'If find a NULL Text node
    End Try
    Return "Nothing"
End Function
```

So even if the passed nodes have NULL text or not, I should get a valid String back, right? And if I am getting a valid string, than String.Chars(0) should have at least a letter? I shouldn't be getting back NULL Strings, correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, what is `StringCleaner.Clean(node.InnerText)` returning?

Comment: An empty string, probably.

Comment: @HansPassant You were correct indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said, it is most likely that node.InnerText is empty, so I would suggest changing this method

```
Function GetTextbyNode(ByVal node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode) As String
    Try
        If not String.isNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) then
           Return StringCleaner.Clean(node.InnerText)
        End If
    Catch
        'If find a NULL Text node
    End Try
    Return "Nothing"
End Function
```

Comment: This was it! I had stupidly assumed that if no Innertext was found, it would return NULL, not an empty string. Looking over the HTML documents, I found some nodes that had a text node in them, but had nothing in them (ex: "") and was not checking for those. Thanks!